# gtk idle_add not running?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk

I have a two-thread application: GUI, and some background work. I'm trying to send requests to the main thread to do GUI updates (move a progress bar), but it doesn't seem to work. I've boiled it down to a really minimal example:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import glib
import gtk

import threading
import sys
import time

def idle():
    sys.stderr.write('Hello from another world.\n')
    sys.stderr.flush()
    gtk.main_quit()

def another_thread():
    time.sleep(1)
    glib.idle_add(idle)

thread = threading.Thread(target=another_thread)
thread.start()
gtk.main()
```

This should, I thought, print something to standard error from the main/GUI thread, but nothing happens. And it doesn't quit, either, so `gtk.main_quit` isn't being called.

Also, adding more output to `stderr` acts weirdly. If I change the thread's function to:

```
sys.stderr.write('----\n')
sys.stderr.write('----\n')
sys.stderr.flush()
sys.stderr.write('After.\n')
sys.stderr.flush()
```

I see 1, sometimes 2 lines out output. It looks like some kind of race condition with the main thread entering `gtk.main`, but I don't know why this would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following makes the above work for me:

A call to `gtk.gdk.threads_init()` before doing anything else: before starting threads, before entering `gtk.main()`. I think in reality, this only needs to be called before entering `gtk.main()`, but it is easy enough to call it while everything is single threaded and simple.

In the idle callback (`idle`, in the example), a call to `gtk.gdk.threads_enter()` before GTK stuff (easy to do just at the top of the function), and a call to `gtk.gdk.threads_leave()`, before the end of the function.

`gtk.gdk.threads_init()` seems to also tell PyGTK not hold the GIL when it goes to sleep - I think I was missing some output from the aux. thread in the example just because the sleeping main thread (sleeping in `gtk.main()`) was still holding the GIL. `gtk.gdk.threads_init()`, as far as I can tell, instills good mojo into PyGTK and GTK+. Because of this, `gtk.gdk.threads_init()` is needed even if you launch a thread that doesn't touch GTK+, doesn't do anything with glib, gobject, etc., just does basic computation.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with pygtk (but I am with glib), and I'm pretty sure that to just add stuff to the main loop you don't need threads_enter() / threads_leave() - glib does all the necessary locking internally after you call threads_init(). The enter/leave functions seem to be needed if you're actually calling GDK/GTK code in the thread,

Comment: @vanza: Reading the source code, I agree. gdk_threads_lock is just a simple mutex lock/unlock.

Answer (score 4):

You need to init glib's thread support before using glib in a multi-threaded environment. Just call:

```
glib.threads_init()
```

Before calling into glib functions.

Comment: I have no idea why this got downvoted - I think it's on the right track. The only thing is, `glib` doesn't seem to have a `threads_init` function. (At least in PyGTK.) It's documented, but it's not there.

Comment: `glib` is part of PyGObject, not PyGtk (anymore).  And on my Ubuntu 10.04 system `glib` does have a working `threads_init`.

Comment: @Jan Claeys: I can `import gobject; gobject.threads_init()`, but not the same with `glib`. pygobject 2.20.0 and pygtk 2.16.0, Gentoo.

Comment: Looks like they changed their API at some point. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 and have glib.threads_init(). (pygtk 2.17.0, pygobject 2.15.3)

Comment: By comparing the API docs between PyGObject 2.14 & 2.16 it seems like between that time they split `gobject` into `gobject` & `glib` modules, and this function hasn't moved since then.  Also, you *should* have [`glib.threads_init()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/2.20/glib-functions.html#function-glib--threads-init) in PyGObject 2.20, unless Gentoo has some weird patch for it.  Or maybe you have multiple versions and are accidentally using the wrong one?

Comment: @vanza: Ubuntu 10.04 has `python-gobject` version 2.21.1

Comment: Yeah, you're right - I was looking at the dependencies for pygtk and not the actual pygobject package.

Comment: This function now spawns a warning that this is no longer needed. The warning gives a url which redirects to another page which then informs you that the information was moved here: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `glib.timeout_add_seconds(1, idle)` and return `False` from `idle()` instead of starting a thread and then sleeping 1 second? Starting an idle function from another thread is quite redundant, since idle functions already run in another thread.

**EDIT:**

By "starting an idle function from another thread is redundant", I meant that you don't have to start an idle function in order to mess with the GUI and update the progress bar. It is a myth that you can't mess with the GUI in other threads.

Let me restate here what is needed to do GTK calls from other threads:

1. Call `glib.threads_init()` or `gobject.threads_init()`, whichever you have, as discussed in vanza's answer.
2. Call `gtk.gdk.threads_init()`. I am pretty sure you are right in your answer, this only has to be called before `gtk.main()`. The C docs suggest calling it before `gtk_init()`, but that's called at import time in PyGTK if I'm not mistaken.
3. Bracket your call to `gtk.main()` between `gtk.gdk.threads_enter()` and `gtk.gdk.threads_leave()`.
4. Bracket any calls to GTK functions from:

   - threads other than the main thread
   - idle functions
   - timeouts
   - basically any callback other than signal handlers

   between `gtk.gdk.threads_enter()` and `gtk.gdk.threads_leave()`.

Note that instead of surrounding your calls with `enter`/`leave` pairs, you can also use [`with gtk.gdk.lock:`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/gdk-functions.html#function-gdk--lock) and do your calls within that `with`-block.

Here are some resources which also explain the matter:

- http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDK_Threads.html
- http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness.html

Comment: While the example is obviously quite redundant, as the question states, it's a minimal example of a larger problem. The actual program has a background thread doing work, and needs to update a GUI progress bar. The GTK docs seem to say that you should not go about screwing with the GUI is any old thread, so I'm dispatching a call back to the main thread with `idle_add` which, as my understanding goes, runs in the thread that's polling that mainloop - the main thread, in this case.

Comment: I'm sorry my answer wasn't useful to you (I didn't realize the sleep command wasn't part of the real work you wanted to do), but I think you missed my point. I will edit it and try to explain more clearly.