# Is it possible to edit menu items in runtime in Python using gtk?

Tags: python, pygtk

I am writing simple app in python, I want to write a menu using PyGtk. The problem is that under "Connect" menu item I want to have a list of avaliable devices which changes during program operation. So far my code for creating menu items is as below:

```
import gtk
import gobject

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        gobject.timeout_add(2000, self.AddNewDevice_TEST)   

        table = gtk.Table(2,1,False)
        window.add(table)

        menubar = gtk.MenuBar()

        self.connectMenu = gtk.Menu()
        connectItem = gtk.MenuItem("Connect")
        connectItem.set_submenu(self.connectMenu)

        dev1 = gtk.MenuItem("device1")
        dev1.connect("activate", self.connectToDev)
        self.connectMenu.append(dev1)

        menubar.append(connectItem)

        table.attach(menubar, 0,1,0,1)

        window.show_all()   

    def connectToDev(self, device):
        pass

    def AddNewDevice_TEST(self):
        dev = gtk.MenuItem("device")
        dev.connect("activate", self.connectToDev)
        self.connectMenu.append(dev)


if __name__=='__main__':
    gui = Foo()
    gtk.main()
```

Problem is that when new device appears in my system or it is disconnected I want to add it or remove it from the list under "Connect".
I am able to edit list of devices in menu but after calling gtk.main() I can't make changes any more. Is there any way to do that in runtime?

Comment: Just FYI, pygtk uses the outdated Gtk version 2. The current version is Gtk3, which you import with `from gi.repository import Gtk`.

Comment: You can modify the Menu during runtime exactly the same way you do it here. If it doesn't work, you're doing something wrong. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I edited the code, that's what I have. I need table because of the other part of my app

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work ok now. I don't know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: If your program is multithreaded, make sure not to modify the GUI from a thread. You can use `idle_add` to let the mainloop execute a function; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579221/gtk-idle-add-not-running) for more info about multithreading in gtk.

Answer (score 0):

You can change menu items during runtime in a different thread, e.g. `GObject.idle_add(self.connectMenu.remove, dev1)` or `GObject.idle_add(self.connectMenu.append, dev1)`. The methods mentioned for GtkMenuShell in the [GNOME Developer Documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuShell.html) might be helpful.

Don't forget to call `show()` on the MenuItems as mentioned in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158860/dynamically-modifying-refreshing-menu-contents-in-pygtk).